# What is the default amount of swap storage space?

Tags: swap

Does Ubuntu 22.04 create a swap file by default? What is the default amount of storage allocated to the swap file? Please share the **documentation link** regarding these details.

Comment: Zero swap is the "default". Having swap controls what the system does when programs ask for more memory than is available. I use 1-1.5 x RAM for my systems. YMMV. You need at least 1 x RAM to hibernate. Swap files must be contiguous. Read `man mkswap swapon fstab mount sudo`.